# Spring Boot JPA: How to change the way an attribute is saved

Tags: spring, jpa, insert, hex

I need to find a way to insert an entity with attributes using JPA. One of the attribute is representing a hexstring. Because of the used DB and other requirements I am forced to insert this string with the syntax X'stringValue' into the DB.

Unfortunately I didn't find any way to insert this syntax. I tried it with @Query (native sql) and @Columntransformer(X'?'), but nothing helps, because the questionmark is always used as a string because of the single quotes.

I would need something like:
`Hibernate:  insert  into table (SPECIAL_COLUMN, NORMAL_COLUMN)  values (X'?', ?)`

Answer (score 0):

Implement an [AttributeConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html). Before an attribute is saved to DB, its value will be computed using `convertToDatabaseColumn()`. When you read this attribute from DB, the value in the DB will be converted using `convertToEntityAttribute()` and then set to the attribute.

Briefly, it can look as follows:

```
public class XPrefixConverter implements AttributeConverter<String , String> {

    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
        if (attribute != null) {
            return HexFormat.of().withPrefix("X").formatHex(attribute.getBytes());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String attribute) {
        if (attribute = null) {
            return new String(HexFormat.of().withPrefix("X").parseHex(value));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Then use it for specific attribute:

```
@Convert( converter = XPrefixConverter.class )
private String hexString;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but when I do so the attribute is a whole string "X'someValue'" that is inserted into the DB like X'someValue'. I don't want this.  The X'' should not be part of the string itself. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @mentallurg as far as I can see, TC is working with DB which have special SQL grammar which allows to insert/update binary data via "binding" X'hexstr' literals, however I'm afraid that it is either a feature of SQL-client (in that case TC just need to bind byte array) or JDBC driver (something similar to https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/escapes/), in that case it is required to define own type in HBN.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov: 1) *"I can see ... DB which have special SQL grammar"* - I don't see that. The OP says nothing about any special grammar. 2) The question asks about how to reach the desired value conversion in JPA. I show that there is a standard way in JPA for this. AttributeConverter was designed exactly for this purpose.

Comment: @mentallurg check for example https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=considerations-example-use-blob-data-type: `INSERT INTO TABBLOB VALUES('%s', BLOB(x'%s'))` - same `X'` syntax.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov: 1) Your example converts a hexadecimal string into a blob. Where the the OP has normal string values that need to be converted into a hexadecimal string. 2) Your example is vendor specific, namely for DB2. Where the AttributeConverter allows to implement *any* logic and it will work for *any* database.

Comment: Unfortunately it just inserts the hexstring without X'value' notation into the DB when using Hexformat.of().formatHex(bytes[]). When I insert a byte array it works well and the mapping is correct. But I can't read the column afterwards with the AttributeConverter, because it would expect a byte[] in the convertToEntityAttribute() method and it's just a string(VARCHAR). Do have a solution for this?

Comment: You said *"X'stringValue' into the DB"*. I understood that as target column has string type (CHAR, VARCHAR, CLOB). It seems your description was not correct. First tell pls what is the type of the target column. Ist it CHAR, VARCHAR, CLOB, BLOB?

Comment: Then sorry for the misunderstanding. The type of the target column is VARCHAR. So that's correct. Nevertheless I should not insert a string "X'value'" instead something like X'hexString'. So the X and the single quotes are around the string I want to insert and not directly part of the string. I think this X belongs to the DB2 grammer.

Comment: OK. Then add a prefix "X". See update.

Comment: Is there an other way? Because this prefix "X" just add a X in front of every hex byte (e.g. "X0eXacXf7X89Xb7Xb8Xe2Xb7...") Actually it should look cryptically like "Ð7i¼½S¼/¸ß ½÷½Ïü..." in my DB tool when I select the row.

Comment: Just play with the converter and do what you need. If need prefix for the whole string, just write the code correspondingly: `"X" + HexFormat.of().formatHex()` or similar. And in the other Method do the parsing correspondingly: Remove the first character and parse the rest.